# One to Many relationship in JPA

Tags: jpa

i am facing one problem related to One to Many relation. I have two Entities called 
Mentor and Experience, the relationship between two entities are one to Many relationship means mentor can have multiple experiences. see  following code

public class Mentors {

```
@Id
private String userId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "T_MENTORS_userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
private Collection<Experience> experience;
}
```

**Experience Entity**

```
public class Experience {

    @Id
    private long experienceID;
```

}

How can i find the experiences against any specific USER as i don't have any user Id field in experience entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mentor mentor = em.find(Mentor.class, specificUserId);
Collection<Experience> specificUserExperiences = mentor.getExperiences();
```

Or, using a query:

```
select e from Mentor m left join m.experiences e where m.userId = :specificUserId;
```